# Redux with React design of dispatch

Tags: reactjs, oop, redux, design-patterns

I am fairly new to Redux and even though I understand reducers and dispatching, I am puzzled by the way Redux is used in React components.

Why use hooks like `useSelector` and `useDispatch` with fairly complicated (but still customized) action creators while we can abstract the entire process away by providing an interface that can access the state.

For example what would be wrong with the below definition:

`export function setDefaultUnits(measure_: keyof defaultUnits_state_type_, quantity_: Quantity, store_: Store = store)`

and subsequent call from within a component:

`setDefaultUnits('distance', Quantity('meters'))` that implicitly accesses the current store, serializes the Quantity object and stores it in the state but **effectively abstracts away state implementation details**?

I think automating serialization and de-serialization are important enough to use entirely custom functions for the state that are then used in React components.

Is there a design philosophy that compels us to use useDispatch and useSelector?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you're suggesting, it just wouldn't be redux anymore. In the flux paradigm you need to dispatch actions to mutate the state as a result, you can't just directly access it. In your example, if `setDefaultUnits` is called somewhere, it doesn't happen in a formalized way that other parts of the code can respond to (redux middlewares!), for example. You'd just deviate from the overall architecture. The constraints that come with the flux pattern might seem strange at first, but they're attempts to solve problems and reduce the complexity of large apps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't fully understand the deviation (since under the hood these methods use selectors and dispatches anyway). It just seems odd to me that to get the slightest piece of information e.g. the access token or something as simple as checking whether a user is logged in or logging in a user to have to write long expressions instead of just formalizing these functions. I feel this is what facilitates large app development in the end.

Comment: Well there is the famous "you might not need redux" article from Dan Abramov, possibly interesting for you. It is quite a "bureaucratic" library. The benefits are structure and features like time travel and undo that some apps need. If you don't need those at all, a simpler state management library, or just react context, or custom hooks that encapsulate state might be enough for you.